# HKWorkoutActivityType detail documentation?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

Looking at `HKWorkoutActivityType` enum there are many sports listed.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutactivitytype  I'm trying to find out what specific sample data is available for each given sport, i.e lacrosse...how do I know what HK data I can query for for a given activity type? Or are these just mere names for the workouts with no real difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just names of the workouts so you can differentiate between them.

So each workout has to have an activity type and then you can add any number of samples to a given workout...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a list of all available samples I can query for? I specifically was looking to determine speed (i.e. accelerometer data) or do I need to use Core Motion separately to get that?

Comment: I would think you have to use Core Motion, since HealthKit is more of a system to record data, and not so much as data collector as regards to how much you have ran, how fast, how many steps did you take etc...

Comment: As far as samples go there is a whole list of them...enum `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier`, more info here...https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier

Comment: They provide an example for downhill skiing: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutactivitytype/snowboarding/receiving_downhill_skiing_and_snowboarding_data  I wish they had these examples for all the different types, I think that's what you're asking